# React Navbar Not Collapsing On Link Click

Tags: reactjs, navbar, hamburger-menu

I've created a React NavBar following a tutorial, when I click the burger menu, the nav expands and collapses as expected, but when I click a link on the nav menu, it goes to the page but the nav bar doesn't collapse. I've checked a few questions/guides but they all link to Bootstrap and this code doesn't use Bootstrap, I'd rather not change the NavBar to Bootstrap if it can be avoided! Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "../images/logo.svg";
import { FaAlignRight } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  };
  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.resizeHeaderOnScroll);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.navTransparent);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.navShadow);
  };
  resizeHeaderOnScroll() {
    const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      shrinkOn = 100,
      headerEl = document.getElementById("logo");
    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
      headerEl.classList.add("logoShrink");
      
    } else {
      headerEl.classList.remove("logoShrink");
    }
  }

  navTransparent() {
    const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      shrinkOn = 100,
      headerEl = document.getElementById("navbar");
    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
      headerEl.classList.add("navbarBg");
      
    } else {
      headerEl.classList.remove("navbarBg");
    }

  }
  
  navShadow() {
    const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      shrinkOn = 100,
      headerEl = document.getElementById("navbar");
    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
      headerEl.classList.add("navShadow");
      
    } else {
      headerEl.classList.remove("navShadow");
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <nav id="navbar">
      <div className="nav-center">
        <div className="nav-header">
          <Link to="/">
            <img id="logo" src={logo} alt="" />
          </Link>
          <button type="button" className="nav-btn" onClick={this.handleToggle}>
            <FaAlignRight className="nav-icon" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <ul className={this.state.isOpen ? "nav-links show-nav" : "nav-links"}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/nigelservices">Services</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use an onClick in the link component that does the handleToggle function, so everytime you access a link the sidebar will close as well.

Comment: Okay, I can try that, do you have any links or docs I can look at?

Comment: I dont have any documentation but you can do: <Link to="/nigelservices" onClick{() =>  this.setState({ isOpen: false })}>Services</Link> and that should work. Remember to add that in every link

Comment: I literally just did this after understanding what you mean, can you answer that in the main thread and I can mark it as the solution :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question here you can always do this because the Link component accepts the onClick prop:

```
export default class Navbar extends Component {
 // Rest of your code
 handleLinkClick = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpen: false });
 };

 render() {
  return (
  // Your JSX
   <Link to="/" onClick={handleLinkClick}>Home</Link>
  )
 }
}
```

Remember to add this in every link component.

As a side note you can also use the NavLink component in react router to handle the styling when the route is the current one. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

Comment: Thanks jean182! Appreciate your time massively!!